# repartition in spark streaming is taking more time?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I am running a spark application where data comes in every 1 minute. No of repartitions i am doing is 48. It is running on 12 executor with 4G as executor memory and executor-cores=4.

Below are the streaming batches processing time

[image]

Here we can see that some of the batches are taking around 20 sec but some are taking around 45 sec

I further drilled down in one of the batch which is taking less time. Below is the image.

[image]

and the one which is taking more time.

[image]

Here we can see more time is taken in repartitioning task, but above one was not taking much time in repartitioning. Its happening with every 3-4 batch. The data is coming from kafka Stream and has only value, no key.

Is there any reason related to spark configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" size, the default value is 200 which is an overkill. Reduce the values and analyse the performance.